# Why does Fedora not include GCC by default?

Tags: fedora, gcc

I just finished a Fedora 21 clean installation. I have updated and upgraded, but I notice the following: GNU GDB is installed by default, as GNU Make is. However, GCC is not. Is that supposed to happen? If so, why is that? And how should I install all necessary components of GCC to work with C? Is `yum install gcc` is enough? Thanks.

Comment: you can use g++, build-essential , automake, autoconf , bison and so on.

Comment: Pretty please, IIRC build-essential is a Debian meta-package. Original question is about Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what sort of install you did, but if you tell it you want a software development you should get gcc I think.  After the fact if you want a lot of those common tools you can do

```
yum groupinstall 'C Development Tools and Libraries'
```

Comment: how different is that installation from yum install gcc only?

Comment: It will install a lot of different packages.  You can run `yum groupinfo 'C Development Tools and Libraries'` to see all the things it will install.  It's a shortcut to install a bunch of packages you'll probably want if you're doing development with C and the like

Comment: This command shows that it will also install gdb and make, as long as other many packages. My system, somehow, has already gdb and make. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Nope, if the packages are already installed it will just skip over them, if they need to be upgraded to a newer version it will do that